# Eclipse C++ Inheritance issue

Tags: c++, inheritance

I've been working on this code fighting one little error the entire time, in my OvernightPackage.h file. OvernightPackage inherits from the superclass Package, but it keeps throwing the error: "expected class name" I also have another class TwoDayPackage, and it inherits just fine, and I can't figure out whats different between the two of them.

Heres my code:

main.cpp

```
//============================================================================
// Name        : Assignment4.cpp
//============================================================================

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "Person.h"
#include "Package.h"
#include "TwoDayPackage.h"
#include "OvernightPackage.h"



void readFile(char & c, int & i, double & d, double & ed, string attributes[]){
    ifstream input;
    input.open("package.txt");
    input >> c;
    input >> i;
    input >> d;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        input >> attributes[i];
    }
    switch(c){
    case('o'):
    case('O'):
    case('t'):
    case('T'):
        input >> ed;
        break;
    }

}

void printLabel(Package item){

    cout << "********* Shipping Label *******" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Delivery Cost: " << item.costToDeliver() << endl;
    cout << "The package will arrive at its destination in " << item.timeToDeliver() << " days.";
    cout << "From:\n";
    cout << item.getSenderName() << endl;
    cout << item.getSenderAddress() << endl;
    cout << item.getSenderCity() << "," << item.getSenderState() << " " << item.getSenderZip() << endl ;
    cout << "Ship To:\n";
    cout << item.getRecieverName() << endl;
    cout << item.getRecieverAddress() << endl;
    cout << item.getRecieverCity() << "," << item.getRecieverState() << " " << item.getRecieverZip() << endl ;
    cout << "\n******************************";


}

int main() {
    char packageType;
    int weight;
    double costPerOunce, extraData;
    string attributes[10];
    readFile(packageType, weight, costPerOunce, extraData, attributes);
    Person sender = Person(attributes[0],attributes[1],attributes[2],attributes[3],attributes[4]);
    Person receiver = Person(attributes[5],attributes[6],attributes[7],attributes[8],attributes[9]);
    Package package;

    switch(packageType){
    case('p'):
    case('P'):
        package = Package(weight,costPerOunce);
        break;
    case('o'):
    case('O'):
        package = OvernightPackage(weight,costPerOunce,extraData);
        break;
    case('t'):
    case('T'):
        package = TwoDayPackage(weight,costPerOunce,extraData);
        break;
    }
    package.setSender(sender);
    package.setReceiver(receiver);
    printLabel(package);

}
```

Person.h

```
/*
 * Person.h
 *
 *  Created on: Feb 20, 2014
 *      Author: Nate Ashby
 */

#ifndef PERSON_H_
#define PERSON_H_

using namespace std;

class Person{
public:
    Person();
    Person(string name, string address, string city, string state, string zip);
    string getName();
    string getAddress();
    string getCity();
    string getState();
    string getZip();
private:
    string name;
    string address;
    string city;
    string state;
    string zip;
};



#endif /* PERSON_H_ */
```

Person.cpp

```
/*
 * Person.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: Feb 20, 2014
 *      Author: Nate Ashby
 */
#include "Person.h"

using namespace std;

Person::Person(){
    name = "Empty";
    address = "Empty";
    city = "Empty";
    state = "Empty";
    zip = "Empty";
};

Person::Person(string name, string address, string city, string state, string zip){
    this->name = name;
    this->address = address;
    this->city = city;
    this->state = state;
    this->zip = zip;


};
string Person::getName(){return name;};
string Person::getAddress(){return address;};
string Person::getCity(){return city;};
string Person::getState(){return state;};
string Person::getZip(){return zip;};
```

Package.h

```
/*
 * Package.h
 *
 *  Created on: Feb 20, 2014
 *      Author: Nate Ashby
 */

#ifndef PACKAGE_H_
#define PACKAGE_H_


class Package{
public:
    Package();
    Package(int ounces, double costPerOunce);
    int getWeight();
    double getCostPerOunce();
    Person getSender();
    Person getReciever();
    void setWeight(int);
    void setCostPerOunce(double);
    void setSender(Person);
    void setReceiver(Person);
    double costToDeliver();
    std::string timeToDeliver();
    friend class Person;
    std::string getSenderName();
    std::string getSenderAddress();
    std::string getSenderCity();
    std::string getSenderState();
    std::string getSenderZip();
    std::string getRecieverName();
    std::string getRecieverAddress();
    std::string getRecieverCity();
    std::string getRecieverState();
    std::string getRecieverZip();
protected:
    int ounces;
    double costPerOunce;
    Person Sender;
    Person Reciever;
};
```

Package.cpp

```
/*
 * Person.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: Feb 20, 2014
 *      Author: Nate Ashby
 */
#include "Person.h"

using namespace std;

Person::Person(){
    name = "Empty";
    address = "Empty";
    city = "Empty";
    state = "Empty";
    zip = "Empty";
};

Person::Person(string name, string address, string city, string state, string zip){
    this->name = name;
    this->address = address;
    this->city = city;
    this->state = state;
    this->zip = zip;


};
string Person::getName(){return name;};
string Person::getAddress(){return address;};
string Person::getCity(){return city;};
string Person::getState(){return state;};
string Person::getZip(){return zip;};
```

TwoDayPackage.h

```
/*
 * TwoDayPackage.h
 *
 *  Created on: Feb 20, 2014
 *      Author: Nate Ashby
 */

#ifndef TWODAYPACKAGE_H_
#define TWODAYPACKAGE_H_


class TwoDayPackage : public Package{
public:
    TwoDayPackage();
    TwoDayPackage(int,double,double);
    void setIncrease(double);
    double getIncrease();
private:
    double costPerOunceIncrease;
};




#endif /* TWODAYPACKAGE_H_ */
```

TwoDayPackage.cpp

```
/*
 * TwoDayPackage.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: Feb 20, 2014
 *      Author: Nate Ashby
 */
#include "TwoDayPackage.h"

TwoDayPackage::TwoDayPackage(){
    ounces = 0;
    costPerOunce = 0;
    costPerOunceIncrease = 0;
};
TwoDayPackage::TwoDayPackage(int weight, double cost, double rateIncrease){
    ounces = weight;
    costPerOunce = cost;
    costPerOunceIncrease = rateIncrease;
};
void TwoDayPackage::setIncrease(double rateIncrease){ costPerOunceIncrease = rateIncrease;};
double TwoDayPackage::getIncrease(){return costPerOunceIncrease;};
double TwoDayPackage::costToDeliver(){return (ounces * (costPerOunce + costPerOunceIncrease));};
std::string timeToDeliver(){return "2";};
```

OvernightPackage.h

```
/*
 * OvernightPackage.h
 *
 *  Created on: Feb 20, 2014
 *      Author: Nate Ashby
 */

#ifndef OVERNIGHTPACKAGE_H_
#define OVERNIGHTPACKAGE_H_


class OvernightPackage : public Package{
public:
    OvernightPackage();
    OvernightPackage(int, double, double);
    double getRate();
    void setRate(double);
protected:
    double flatRateIncrease;
};


#endif /* OVERNIGHTPACKAGE_H_ */
```

and finally OvernightPackage.cpp

```
/*
 * OvernightPackage.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: Feb 20, 2014
 *      Author: Nate Ashby
 */

#include "OvernightPackage.h"

OvernightPackage::OvernightPackage(){
    ounces = 0;
    costPerOunce = 0;
    flatRateIncrease = 0;
}
OvernightPackage::OvernightPackage(int weight, double costPerOunce, double overnightIncrease){
    this->ounces = weight;
    this->costPerOunce = costPerOunce;
    this->flatRateIncrease = overnightIncrease;
}
double OvernightPackage::getRate(){return flatRateIncrease;};
void OvernightPackage::setRate(double rate){flatRateIncrease = rate;};
double OvernightPackage::costToDeliver(){ return (ounces * costPerOunce + flatRateIncrease);};
std::string timeToDeliver(){return "1";};
```

Comment: TL;DR! Please edit your question to contain the *complete* and *unedited* error log. Then narrow the code down to the lines referenced in the error(s) plus some context.

Comment: Boooah!!! TL;DR; ... And why [tag:eclpse] BTW.

Answer (score 1):

Your issues most likely is due to missing includes. In the classes that inherit you need to include the base class, so add

```
#include "Package.h"
```

to the two inheriting classes. Also, `Package.h` needs an include for `Person.h` and several of the files should include `<string>` since your using it.

By the way, in your example code you posted person.cpp where package.cpp should be, and overall the code is way to long. Before posting next time please read up on how to do a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://www.sscce.org/)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'm new to stackoverflow. Sorry for my lack of sscce knowledge.